# How do I specify metadata for the executable created by the nbm maven plugin

Tags: netbeans-platform, maven-nbm

I'd like to specify the metadata that is visible when I right-click / info on the executable created by the netbeans maven plugin (nbm).

Currently it looks loke this:

[image: File properties of netbeans exe]

I am specifically missing a way to speficy the following:

1. name
2. version

I already specified the organization tag in my pom. But it has no effect.

I looked at the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) for the maven nbm plugin and the official docs, but I could not find anything.

The executuable in netbeans 8.2 has all the required meta-data, so I think there must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

add :
product.display.name=My Product
product.description=the description

in bundles.properties